# Query From SQLite DataBase Android

Tags: cursor, android-sqlite

I am trying to make a query from sqlite database by passing a value. Based on the passed value I need to fetch a unique record if data is available.Below is my code so far I have written

```
    public  String getDataOnlytransid(String Questionid)
    {
       String [] columns=new String[] {TRANS_ID};
       Cursor c=ourDatabse.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,null,TRANS_ID,TRANS_ID + "=?", Questionid,null);

       String result="";

       int iRowID=c.getColumnIndex(TRANS_ID);

       for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
       {
        result=result + c.getString(iRowID); // n is for newline
       }
       c.close();
       return result;

     }
```

Then I am calling above method using below code

```
            final question_savelistDB db = new question_savelistDB(context);
            db.open();
            final String question_id=db.getDataOnlytransid(dataList.get(position).getSaved_qid());
            db.close();
```

But it is giving below error.What is the wrong I am doing

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 1st ORDER BY term out of range - should be between 1 and 1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT trans_id FROM PaymentTable GROUP BY trans_id HAVING trans_id=? ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The 7th argument of the method `query()` is the `ORDER BY` clause of the statement (without the `ORDER BY` keywords) and it should be a string.
Instead, you pass `Questionid` which is an integer and the `ORDER BY` clause becomes:

```
ORDER BY 2
```

You must pass the string `TRANS_ID`, which is the name of the one and only column that your query returns:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabse.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, TRANS_ID, TRANS_ID + "=?", TRANS_ID, null);
```

But, if the column `TRANS_ID` is unique in the table, you don't need the `ORDER BY` clause at all, since you expect 1 row at most in the results, so there is no need to sort and you could just pass `null`.
Also, you don't need the `GROUP BY` clause which is the 5th argument and instead of passing the parameter `Questionid` to a `HAVING` clause you should use the `WHERE` clause:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabse.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, TRANS_ID + "=?", TRANS_ID, null, null, , null, null);
```

Also, there is no need for a loop after you get the cursor.
You should only check if there is a row in the cursor and get the value of its only column:

```
public  String getDataOnlytransid(String Questionid) {
    String [] columns=new String[] {TRANS_ID};
    Cursor c = ourDatabse.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, TRANS_ID + "=?", TRANS_ID, null, null, , null, null);
    String result="";
    if (c.moveToFirst()) result = c.getString(0);
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

Also, you pass the parameter named `Questionid` for a column named `TRANS_ID`. Are you sure this is correct?
If it is, then I assume that you do it because you want to check if that `Questionid` exists in the table.
But you should know that `getDataOnlytransid()`, as it is, it returns the same value as `Questionid` if it exists in the table.